# Pass value from dynamically generated table

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to php.
I have created a code that generates table of products dynamically.
I want to submit particular product to add that product in cart and Product_id should be pass to next page.
I am using form for that. However, the problem is I dont know how to pass value to other page.

## here is my code

```
while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($sql_result,MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
            { 
                $name=$rows['Product_Name'];
                $price=$rows['Price'];
                $srtdesc=$rows['Short_Descr'];
                $dtdescr=$rows['Dtl_Descr'];
                $pid=$rows['Product_ID'];
              echo "<TD align='center'>". $name ."<br />"."$price". "</br>"."$srtdesc"."</br>"."$pid"."<br/>"."<img height=100% width=100% src=images/Products/"."$pid.jpg />"."<input type='submit'/>"."</TD>\n"; 

              if ($columnCounter % 4 == 0) {                 
                    echo "</TR>\n <TR>\n"; 
                }
                $columnCounter = $columnCounter + 1;
            } 
            echo "</TR>\n"; 
          } else { 
            echo "<TR>\n<TD colspan='" . ($i+1) . "'>No Results found!</TD></TR>\n"; 
        } 
        echo "</TBODY>\n</TABLE>\n";
        echo "</DIV>\n";
        echo "</form>";
```

Comment: So are you asking how you should build a shopping cart?  Do you know how to use sessions?

Comment: Do you want to pass the values in the querystring (GET) or hidden away (POST)?

Comment: I know little bit about sessions.

Comment: ya I know GET or Post but I am displaying all the records by using loop so how can I get Id for particular product

Answer (score 0):

One method is to pass the data in a URL.  For example, you could put this in your loop:

```
<a href="somepage.php?product_id=<?php echo $pid ?>">Link Text<a/>
```

Then on somepage.php you would get the id from $_GET['product_id'].

Minor suggestion:  consistency is one of the most important aspects of coding.  Lowercase all your HTML tags.